# how to insert a force or torque sensor to gazebo model？

Tags: gazebo-sensor, gazebo-model

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

as title
thanks a lot

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/241/how-to-insert-a-force-or-torque-sensor-to-gazebo-model%EF%BC%9F/) by [lugd1229](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/79/lugd1229/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 75 on 2012-11-18

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [skhan](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/266/skhan/) on 2013-04-05**:
No one is here to answer it =(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi Skhan,
sorry for the late reply, one way to do this is to create a model plugin, for example, see [this tutorial on how to create a model plugin](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.5/plugins/model_manipulation_plugin).  In the plugin update loop, you can get the force torque information from one of the joints in the model by calling:

```
    physics::JointWrench wrench = this->model->GetJoint("...your model joint name...")->GetForceTorque(0u);
```

On the [SDF](http://gazebosim.org/sdf/dev.html) side, in your model, you must set `<provide_feedback>` to true for this to work.

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) with karma: 1873 on 2013-04-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [iche033](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/58/iche033/) on 2013-04-05**:
you can also create a contact sensor as described in this tutorial: http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.5/sensors/contact

**Comment by [skhan](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/266/skhan/) on 2013-04-09**:
Thanks guys =)

**Comment by [Lucas Walter](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/531/lucas-walter/) on 2014-11-13**:
http://www.gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=contact_sensor&cat=sensors is the new link to the sensor contact tutorial, the above wiki link is dead now.